# Retrieve filename from NSURL

Tags: nsurl

I have a URL

http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/honda_v4_concept_widescreen_bike-wide.jpg

I want to extract the file name which is "honda_v4_concept_widescreen_bike-wide.jpg"

How can I can do this?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The code below should work. Updated it so I removed the top statement. I could've used NSString vs const char * or std::string from C++ but thought C Character Pointers would be quite appropriate for this case in point.

Also revamped this so it's in it's own concise function:

```
-(NSString*) extractFile:(const char*) url 
{
    NSURL *yourURL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                     [NSString stringWithCString:url 
                                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    return [yourURL lastPathComponent];
}
```

**to use:**

```
const char *path_ = "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/honda_v4_concept_widescreen_bike-wide.jpg";
NSLog(@"\t\tYour Extracted file: \n\t%@", [self extractFile:path_]);
```

Comment: I strongly recommend **against** the first code snippet here. The second is fine though

Comment: @MikeAbdullah why is that?

Comment: 1. It's pretending a URL is a path; they're not. If the URL happened to have any components after the path (i.e. parameter, fragment or query), that would screw up this routine

Comment: 2. Less important, but still, it's creating a new, intermediate, string object, which is needlessly wasteful

Comment: `NSURL.lastPathComponent` will even work for `fileReferenceURL`-style URLs. Using the `absoluteString` instead will result in "id=65134..."

Comment: This also doesn't work if the filename contains spaces or any other URL-encoded symbols.

Comment: Please remove the first answer it will not work consistently. Second is good thou.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 3:

```
let urlString = "http://www.hdwallpapers.in/walls/honda_v4_concept_widescreen_bike-wide.jpg"
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
  print("file name: \(url.lastPathComponent)")
} else {
  print("error - not a valid url!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below works. absoluteString is recommended in another answer, but it doesn't work correctly if there are (e.g.) spaces in the filename.

```
NSString *JPEGfilename = [[yourURL path] lastPathComponent];
```

Answer (score -4):

simply use basename `basename()` function

```
$url = http://www.fullhdwallpapers.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Logan-Movie-Kid-2017-680x425.jpg

echo basename($url);
```

Comment: This appears to be PHP – the author specifies that they have a `NSURL` which implies that they'd like an answer in Swift or Objective-C.