# What is the easiest way to get the file name from an NSUrl in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nsurl

I have an NSUrl object and want to read the file name. While searching for existing solutions on StackOverflow I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/19964302/25282 which is for iOS but it uses syntax like `return [yourURL lastPathComponent];` where it is unclear to me how to translate it into the C# that I have to use in Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: You can try this `string fileName = (new NSUrl(file.Url, false)).LastPathComponent;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the equivalent C# for this Obj-C code

```
return [yourURL lastPathComponent];
```

is

```
return yourURL.LastPathComponent;
```

where `yourURL` is a `NSUrl`;